# Limit total number of jobs within nested or concurrent GNU Parallel invocations

Tags: gnu-parallel

This is a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411266/calling-gnu-parallel-from-gnu-parallel) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052454/gnu-parallel-nested-parallelism) on nested GNU Parallel. Utlimately what I want to achieve is to leave my Makefile untouched except by changing the `SHELL=` variable and distribute jobs using `parallel` across all my machines.

Is there a way to ensure that concurrent executions of GNU Parallel respect the `--jobs` clause specified in the outer invocation? Or some other way to get a limit on the total number of jobs across parallel invocations? For example: I'd like the inner slot in the output below to always be `1`, i.e., the `slot 1-2` on line three of the output violates the condition.

```sh
~• inner_par="parallel -I // --slotreplace '/%/' --seqreplace '/#/'"
~• cmd='echo id {#}-/#/, slot {%}-/%/, arg {}-//'
~• seq 2 | parallel -j 1 "seq {} | $inner_par $cmd"
id 1-1, slot 1-1, arg 1-1
id 2-1, slot 1-1, arg 2-1
id 2-2, slot 1-2, arg 2-2
~•
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `sem`?

```
parallel -j 10 parallel -j 20 sem -j 30 --id myid mycmd
```

This will start 200 `sem`s, but only run 30 `mycmd`s in parallel.

Comment: Another way to achieve what I want is to start Parallel following the "simple queue" example from the doc. The trouble there is capturing the exit code of the right job and making the `SHELL=` wrapper wait for that specific job to complete. I'm looking into doing a `wc` to get the job id, but that again requires a shared semaphore. Furthermore, when a job fails and is restarted does it keep the same JobId?

Comment: That might work. But use `PARALLEL_SHELL=` instead of `SHELL=`. JobIDs remain the same.